# How to count total number of products on webpage and verify if those are correct with Selenium webdriver in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to write script to count total no of products on this page http://www.samsung.com/us/video/home-audio/all-products and then need to match with " Showing 1-15 of 38 Matching Products" top text with selenium webdriver in Java. Can you someone suggest me piece of code?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What? What worked? What did not? Have a careful read through [ask].

Comment: What have u tried? We will surely help u but we need to know where u got stuck...

Comment: If you are having trouble figuring out where to begin, it is good practice to look at the [Javadoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below java code will help you do the task

Here we create a driver instance go to the website url take all the products into a list and compare it with the text "1-15 of 38 Matching Products"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.samsung.com/us/video/home-audio/all-products");

        List products = driver.findElements(By.className("product-image"));

        String pagination_no[]=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='category_filter']/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1")).getText().split(" ");

        String[] pagination=pagination_no[1].split("-");

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(pagination[1]),products.size());       

       }
}
```

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Comment: @Vicky, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923932/how-verify-each-product-on-a-webpage-has-a-picture-using-webdriver?noredirect=1#comment69060749_40923932