# How to verify that each product on a webpage has a picture, using webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Using selenium webdriver (Java), I am thinking that the best way to verify that each product on a web page has a picture is to take a screenshot of that page, which obviously will show all the 30 products and their images, all in one go.

My code is:

```
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("Filepath\\"));
```

Is this actually the best option or is there a more subtle or robust method of achieving this? If yes, can someone please share snippets?

Comment: Do you want to check 1) that each products element has an img element? 2) That every image exists? 3) That every image is actually visible by the user? If the answer is 3 and you really want to be sure that the images show, I think the screenshot strategy is a good idea. I'll develop options 1 or 2 depending on what you need.

Comment: @Y-B Cause, each of the images is embedded in img tag and two of the listed products do not have an image, so not visible to the user. Others have an image each. Other than screenshot, can we verify that each product has an image and obviously, that some don't?

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going! :) Please provide an html example and I'll show you.

Comment: When I inspect one image, it's matching nodes for all the 30 images

Comment: I'm with Y-BCause, I think this is possible but we'll need a link to the page or some relevant HTML to show you how to do this.